# Sidekiq kills in between without any reason server RAM is approx 8GB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I am working on the **Ruby on rails** application, my `workers` are running on the `sidekiq-6.0.1`. generally I'm using this to send the push notifications on android and ios devices etc.

I'm running **sidekiq** in the background using the following command:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml -e development &
```

**Sidekiq runs in background successfully but after a couple of hours or sometimes in a couple of minutes kills silently.**

There is not any memory issue, My server RAM is 8 GB.

Please help me to get a best way to deal with this case.

Comment: Check the sidekiq logs and see if you have any information there, you can also open a terminal, run the command without the `&` at the end and keep the terminal open to see if it shows anything when it's kiled. Also, are you sure you want to run that with `-e development` and not production?? The only solution is log everything you can and inspect the logs until you find something.

Comment: "There is not any memory issue, My server RAM is 8 GB." - well, it still could be. If you have a leakage in your script and/or another process that is using much RAM for some reason, eventually at the same time, the OOM killer may terminate your process to free up RAM. I'd suggest to also check your system logs for any indications.

Comment: Hmm.. that may be a case, but I have checked in the deep didn't get any scenario.